# Problem about properties of poset category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I have just started my course in Category Theory and I have the following problem.

Let $(P,\leq)$ be  a poset and $Q$ the category which it defines:

a)Under what conditions does $Q$ have a initial element?

b)Give a characterization of monorphism and isomorphism in $Q$

By now I am little lost in this theory but I imagine that:

a)If there exists $p\in{P}$ such that $p\leq{s}\;\forall{s\in{P}}$ then $p$ is a initial object

b)I think that the characterisation must be related to $\leq$, for example that $\leq$ is a total order.

These are only my conjectures about the problem. I don't know if they are true.
Could someone help me to prove them?

Thanks.

Comment: (a) can be rephrased: $P$ has a least element. For a morphism from $r$ to $s$ to be an isomorphism, it's necessary that there is an inverse morphism from $s$ to $r$. Such morphisms can only exist if $r\le s$ and $s\le r$.

Comment: Is that $s=r$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated, $Q$ has an intial object if $P$ has a least element $s$ - meaning no other element is less than $s$.

In a poset, if $a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$, then $a=b$ as stated. This implies that isomorphisms in $Q$ are just equality, or the identity morphism. This has nothing to do if $Q$ is a total order - there are plenty of posets where this is true (something this is taken as the definition of equality in a poset).

A morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a monomorphism if for all morphisms $g_1,g_2:C\rightarrow A$,
$$f\circ g_1 = f\circ g_2 \Rightarrow g_1 = g_2$$

In $Q$, there exists at most 1 morphism between two objects. This makes every morphism a monomorphism.